# xcode tvos simulator unable to connect to network

Tags: networking, simulator, tvos

When the app in tvos simulator connects to the localhost, it works fine.

But when I changed the app to the network , it reported error "cannot load http://xxxxx.js", and I can visit the file's browser.

Comment: Have you tried using `HTTPS` instead of `HTTP`.